# Json associative array accessing in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, web

I am getting response in below format for every product and in a single call there can be many products. I am trying to access this data via jQuery but I'm not able to access it.

```
Productdata['someid'] =  { "Product Json data"}
```

I am using below syntax in jQuery but not getting the data. Please suggest.

```
alert(Productdata['someid']);
```

Comment: It's not Json formatted

Comment: thats not in the JSON format

Answer (score 1):

Its not going as JSON format .

**JSON is a key : value pair format ;**

so your Productdata  should be in below format:

```
Productdata =  { 'someid' : "Product Json data"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that [JavaScript does not support associative arrays](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp) (scroll down to "Associative arrays, no way!"). It has some internal workarounds which make it appear as if it does, but really all it does is just adding the keys as properties.

So you would most likely be able to access it using `Productdata.someid = ...`.

EDIT:
So assuming you have the following JSON string: `{"id":"123"}` (which is valid JSON), you can use it like this:

```
var jsonString = '{"id":"123"}';
var parsedJSON = $.parseJSON(jsonString);
var productID = "product_" + parsedJSON.id;
```

Does this help?

Some useful links: [JSON format checker to make sure the JSON is valid](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/).

Unfortunately I wasn't allowed to add more than 2 links, so the jQuery parseJSON function link is still in the comment below.

Comment: thanks for your reverts , if I render json like

Product_1  = {Json data}
Product_2

so how I will access it in jquery method because I will be having id 
= 1 or 2 etc

Now I will make a variable 
var id = "value from a hidden field"   (assume 1)
var variabletofetch =  "Product_"+id

Now variable to fetch will be Product_1
now how I will access this value as a variable ?

Comment: @user3592182 Are you getting valid JSON? Are you using [the proper stringify/parse](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) functions within jQuery? Try and use a [JSON format checker](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) to make sure the JSON is valid.

Comment: @user3592182 Has your problem been solved? If so it would be nice if you marked one of the responses as an answer (if it was, of course). Otherwise, let us know what the continued problem seems to be.

Comment: Problem was resolved by adding var productJson = new Array() in my js file .
Thanks for your support :)

Answer (score 0):

A Json like this

```
var data={"name":"somebody"};
```

To call

```
return data.name
```

Or

```
return data["name"]
```